# String.Format not taking 4th object

Tags: c#, string.format

Here is my prob, I wanted String.Format() function should take 4 objects and format string. But it throws *"Input string not in a correct format error"*.

Here is my code,

```
string jsonData = string.Format("{{\"sectionTitle\":\"{0}\",\"strPushMsg\":\"{1}\",\"Language\":\"{2}\",}\",\"articleid\":\"{3}\"}}", urlsectiontitle, formatHeadline, Language, articleid);
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You can not use  this character "}" in string format as main string, Should use "}}"

Comment: @Peyman: Yes, you can. You have to double it `{{`.

Comment: Any reason for wanting to construct JSON by hand here, rather than creating a simple DTO and then letting a library handle the conversion?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I knew it sorry It was incorrect char (mistyping), I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
>   \"{2}\",}\"
> ```

Looks like you need to escape that closing brace by doubling it:

```
string.Format("{{\"sectionTitle\":\"{0}\",\"strPushMsg\":\"{1}\",\"Language\":\"{2}\",}}\",\"articleid\":\"{3}\"}}", urlsectiontitle, formatHeadline, Language, articleid);
```

It appears you are creating JSON. This can use single quotes (which would avoid all the escaping), but even better use a tool like [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.8) designed to create JSON. While your (partial) structure here is quite small (the unmatched `}` shows this is only partial), and the JSON gets bigger it is much easier to use a tool to get it right.